# How to automate CentOS7 minimal kickstart installation using OEMDRV volume?

Tags: automation, installation, centos, centos7, boot

I'm trying to automate the installation process of CentOS7 minimal in VirtualBox. Kickstart file is the solution. I find putting ks.cfg file into OEMDRV.vhdm disk and mounting it to VM memory the easiest way to give the VM access to the configuration file. 
Anaconda reads ks.cfg file, as it pointed out mistake in spelling, but once the file is properly written the VM runs an error, same happens if the ks.cfg file is empty:

```
The I/O cache encountered an error while updating data in medium "ahci- 
0-1" (rc=VERR_ACCESS_DENIED). Make sure there is enough free space on the 
disk and that the disk is working properly. Operation can be resumed 
afterwards.
```

The host is Windows 10, below is my ks.cfg file. The file is taken of already existing centOS7 minimal VM.

```
#version=DEVEL
# System authorization information
auth --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
# Use CDROM installation media
cdrom
# Use cmdline/text/graphical install
graphical
# Run the Setup Agent on first boot
firstboot --enable
ignoredisk --only-use=sda
# Keyboard layouts
keyboard --vckeymap=us --xlayouts='us'
# System language
lang en_US.UTF-8

# Network information
network  --bootproto=dhcp --device=enp0s3 --ipv6=auto --activate
network  --hostname=localhost.localdomain

# Root password #working on --isctrypted rootpw
rootpw --iscrypted $6$6eqrvzKwp2ST4PMi$VUqUy8G/AsbaZK9XbtqlQcSIZjZ7QQk5yFqe5h/91YwM3GI3PjxEASc062EFPgGjvsmMxcLuKvx8d69KLplYJ1
# System services
services --disabled="chronyd"
# System timezone
timezone Europe/Warsaw --isUtc --nontp
# User
user --groups=wheel --name=secutest --password=$6$Ct923BcyZG.13TR2$jEUcu5tlvncoejaWa9eof.5GL1oU3wLVe0zEWLDrpKY6oXJhGeV4CRvoiYfFeC1IpkPeaXc1z912E3HdvOS/t/ --iscrypted --gecos="secutest"
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --append=" crashkernel=auto" --location=mbr --boot-drive=sda

%packages
@^minimal
@core
kexec-tools

%end

%addon com_redhat_kdump --enable --reserve-mb='auto'

%end

%anaconda
pwpolicy root --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --notempty
pwpolicy user --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --emptyok
pwpolicy luks --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --notempty
%end

reboot
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use OEMDRV.iso, ISO disk type. Next OEMDRV disk has to be mounted to VM's SATA controller.

This command creates OEMDV.iso file with volume labeled 'OEMDRV' out of folder, which is exactly what we need.

```
$ mkisofs -V OEMDRV -o OEMDRV.iso path/to/directory
```